# Using client in different files

Tags: discord.js

Is it possible to use the client/bot constant across different files?
My index.js file has gotten pretty clogged up, so I tried splitting different functions into different files.

I already tried exporting the bot constant from index.js:

```js
// in index.js
module.exports = {
   Gbot: bot
}

// in different file
const index = require('../index.js')
const bot = index.Gbot

bot.on('message', message => {
    message.channel.send("test")
})
```

The second file does not do anything, it does not respond with "test"
There is no errors either

Is this not possible or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0):

This is possible, but why do you want to do that? If you are using a Command Handler you define `client` or `bot` to use it everywhere. And if not you are running everything in `index.js`, the file where you defined `client` or `bot`.

Edit:

```js
//index.js
module.exports.Gbot = bot;

//other file
const index = require("../index.js");
const bot = index.Gbot;
```

Comment: Well how would I define it so I can use it everywhere?
Alright I already have that and it doesnt work

Comment: This is literally what I already have and it doesnt work

Comment: @BackspaceRGB, well it is defferent, because you created an object to export. For me it works without any issues.

Comment: I tried logging the id of the user of the bot, nothing got logged, no errors either. I also tried the example from the original post with the "test" message thing, did not work either